# Add group for user in LDAP by group name instead of gid

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

I want to set a group for LDAP user. But instead of using gid, I want to set a group by name. How can I do that?

this is my ldif config for create a user :

```
dn: uid=derek.curtis,ou=People,dc=domain,dc=com
uid: derek.curtis
cn: Derek.curtis
uidnumber: 3001
gidnumber: 10001
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
objectClass: ldapPublicKey
userPassword: {CRYPT}cr5y5J6F67Ci2
shadowLastChange: 15140
shadowMin: 0
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/derek.curtis
sshPublicKey:
```

Answer (score 0):

The posixAccount object class requires you to add the gid number (i.e. it's not an optional attribute). So the short answer is that there is no easy way of doing what you want.